# Hex Encoding and Decoding

Tags: encoding, hex, decoding

I have two modules in some 3rd party application(it does not have any documentation and I cannot reveal application name due to confidentiality). One module outputs only integers and other outputs only floating point numbers.

The module that outputs integers has very simple data format as it was HEX representation of numbers in reverse byte order. So, I am able to decode it successfully. But having issues in decoding HEX representation of floating point numbers.

The data below shows the data dump in HEX followed by the expected converted value. I have a little information about its representation that the last two bytes are some sort of CRC, so, it is like 8 byte number with two CRC bytes. 
I have highlighted the 8 bytes that needs to be converted and their expected value is given below :

Dataset 1:  **02 B5 E6 7B 15 C8 0C 00** 0A F9   =   999359.533

Dataset 2: **7C 4C 3A 00 00 00 00 00** B7 4C    =   0.001

Can anyone suggest something here, I have tried many encoding schemes including IEEE formats also. I do not have any other relevant information that I can share(I know it will be a hit and trial technique to solve this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this helps but:

```
02 B5 E6 7B 15 C8 0C 00 = 0x000CC8157BE6B502 = 3597694319113474

7C 4C 3A 00 00 00 00 00 = 0x00000000003A4C7C = 3820668
```

and

3597694319113474 / 3600000000 = **999359.533**1

3820668 / 3600000000 = **0.001**061297

So within a certain amount of rounding maybe they are fixed point numbers in fractions of 3600000000?

Can you get some more data points?

Comment: Thanks Peter I have tried applying it in other data points and are getting correct value. You have reversed the HEX representation then calculate its equivalent decimal value and divide it by 3600000000. Can you please let me know why you have divided the decimal representation by 3600000000?

Comment: You mentioned that your integer module output in reverse order (which I took to be little-endian). So I converted the bytes to decimal and noticed that they were approximately in proportion to the 'target' numbers. Then I just worked out the ratios  3597694319113474 / 999359.533 and 3820668 / 0.001. Both were close to 3600000000 so I guessed that was the correct factor to use. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes for some it may and for some it may not. So, to validate this I am currently testing it on other data points also. Anyways Thanks Peter for your approach !!!!

Comment: Great, let me know if there's anything I can add - otherwise, please can you mark this as the answer?

Comment: I have accepted this, thanks once again. One quick question here: If I need to document this solution, then how can I explain this 3600000000 factor as this is just a value coming from ratio nothing standard value?